# Solving Minimum swaps hackerrank question in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question about the Minimum Swap question on Hackerrank.

Basically the question is to find the number of swaps required to sort the array.

The array doesn't contain any duplicated elements.

Here is my code but I seem to get a wrong answer. Particularly, I get 4 times the array length for the vector temp.

```
int minimumSwaps(vector<int> arr) {

int n = arr.size();
int count_swap = 0;

vector<int> temp;

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    cout << temp.size()<<"\n";
    if(arr[i] == i+1){

        temp.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    else{

        int initial_val = arr[i];

        int next_val = arr[arr[i] - 1];

        temp.push_back(initial_val);

        while(next_val != initial_val){

            temp.push_back(next_val);

            next_val = arr[next_val - 1];

            count_swap += 1;
            }
        }
    if (temp.size() == n){
        break;
    }      

}
print(temp);
return count_swap;


}
```

My approach was to find a cyclic loop in the array and the min number of swaps required is that number - 1.

So for example, if we have arr = [2,3,4,1,5]

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2

So there is a loop of length 4. Hence the min swap required is 4-1 =3. (Since the other 5 is already in place and will have loop length =1 hence 0 swaps required).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm iterates over each element in the vector, and then proceeds to determine the cycle at that element. It therefore encounters the first cycle four times. The algorithm should likely iterate over the cycles in the vector instead.

Comment: Well that's why I added the `if temp.size() == n break`

Comment: Your for loop increments the index `i` by one in each iteration. If it would instead increment it so that the index points to the beginning of the next cycle, that would probably give the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yup I agree but hence I set the if condition in the next line to break away from the entire loop once the temp.size reaches the original array size which means all the elements were visited.